# How to style custom shortcode in WordPress editor

Tags: wordpress, styles, shortcode

I would like to style custom shortcode in tinyMCE editor when editing post, just like default WordPress gallery. So in HTML tab there will be shortcode but in Editor tab there will be styled shortcode.
Cannot find how does WordPress do it with its gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to render the shortcode in your tinymce editor. This question was answered before: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36568/solution-to-render-shortcodes-in-admin-editor

Comment: Thank you, yes this is exactly what I need.